# Derivation at a point factors through derivation on algebra of germs

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold and $C_x^{\infty}(M,\mathbb R)$ be the algebra of germs of smooth functions on $M$ at $x$. A derivation of $C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb R)$ *at a point $x$* is a linear map $D:C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ which satisfies $$D(f\cdot g)=Df\cdot g(x)+f(x)\cdot Dg$$

How can I show that a derivation of $C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb R)$ at a point $x$ factors to a derivation of $C_x ^{\infty}(M,\mathbb R)$?

**Edit:** I now understand the intended formulation is

> Show that a derivation of $C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb R)$ at a point $x$ factors to a derivation of $C_x ^{\infty}(M,\mathbb R)$ ***at $x$***.

Hence, the factoring is just through the projection taking a smooth function defined in an open neighborhood of $x$ to its germ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any global derivation $D\colon C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})\to C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$, we can form a derivation $D_x\colon C_x^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ by specifying how it should act on germs. So let $[f]_x$ be a germ, i.e. an equivalence class of partial functions $(f,U)$ on neighborhoods $U\ni x$ that agree on their overlaps. We will simply pick any partial function $(f,U)$ in the equivalence class and define
$$
D_x([f]_x)=\left. D(f)\right|_x.
$$
It is clear that this satisfies the properties of a derivation at $x$, since $D$ satisfies these properties pointwise.

Checking that it *factors* amounts to showing that this definition is well-defined; that is, it should be independent of which partial function $(f,U)$ we chose to represent $[f]_x$ by. But this is simply the statement that *derivatives are local*:
$$
\text{If two functions agree on a neighborhood of $x$, then their derivatives agree at $x$.}
$$

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I added in the edit. I was confused at first because the word "at $x$" did not explicitly appear a second time, but there's no other possible meaning.

Comment: Yes your interpretation is correct; in this case the "at $x$" is implied.

Comment: In the second paragraph (i.e., 'Checking that ... '), why do we assume that a derivation at a point $x \in U$ is a derivative?

Comment: How can we even make this definition, when $f \not\in C^\infty(M)$, but instead in a class of smooth functions of some smaller subset?